# Method for Calling out a class(widget) after a button is pressed?

Tags: android

I'm quite new to android programming, currently working on a project for visually impaired personnels. I have made a menu with 3 buttons, one for "time", another for "date" and the last button for "weather" all 3 buttons  with text to speech function added to them. I also have an analog clock widget in my workspace as a different project from my menu project. Now, I want to make it so that when the "time" button is pressed, it will start/activate the analog clock widget. How can I integrate the two projects together and the method to call out the class of the analog clock widget once the "Time" button is pressed?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm new myself to Android!

First thought I had was using an Intent to start your other application within the current application, and use a bundle to capture the actions made when closed. However I haven't called an external app from within an app myself before so try looking here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Or, you could just copy the class into your current project and open it with a normal class calling intent.

Hope this was helpful!